# clearInterval is not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

SetInterval is working fine, but clearInterval is not working

See my code, i have parent class Channel and and Child class Body, within body when componentDidMount is called, then i setInterval for function refreshState. In refreshState function i try to clearInterval which is not working

```
var Header = require('../../common/header.jsx');
var Sidebar = require('../../common/sidebar.jsx');
var Footer = require('../../common/footer.jsx');

var Body = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.intervalId  = setInterval(this.refreshStats, 1000);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  },

  refreshStats: function() {
        console.log(this.intervalId);
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Container id='body'>
        <Grid>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <PanelContainer>
                <Panel>
                  <PanelBody>
                    Test
                  </PanelBody>
                </Panel>
              </PanelContainer>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    );
  }
});

var Channel = React.createClass({
  mixins: [SidebarMixin, State],
  render: function() {
    var classes = React.addons.classSet({
      'container-open': this.state.open
    });
    return (
      <Container id='container' className={classes}>
        <Sidebar />
        <Header />
        <Body />
        <Footer />
      </Container>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Channel;
```

Answer (score 20):

Another way is to save it directly on `this`:

```
var Body = React.createClass({

componentDidMount: function() {
    this.intervalId  = setInterval(this.refreshStats, 1000);
},

componentWillUnmount: function(){
   clearInterval(this.intervalId);
},

refreshStats: function() {
    console.log(this.intervalId);
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
},

render: function() {
    ...
}
});
```

This requires fewer lines of code but it feels a little less clean. I myself save it on `state` as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31023957/274677) suggests, but I am posting this in case someone more knowledgeable might comment on which method is more idiomatic.

Note also that by using the [React Timer mixin](https://github.com/reactjs/react-timer-mixin) you don't have to worry about unmount cleanup - this applies to whether you save the `intervalId` in `state` or on `this`.

Comment: currently this is what the react documentation suggests

Comment: This worked for me. I was having problems clearing the interval using state even if I used setState to make it null. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) uses `this` to store intervalId

Answer (score 17):

In order to *keep a handle* on the `intervalId`, you would need to save it in `state`:

```
var Body = React.createClass({

  getInitialState = function() {
    return {};
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    intervalId  = setInterval(this.refreshStats, 1000);
    this.setState({intervalId: intervalId});
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
  },

  refreshStats: function() {
    console.log(this.state.intervalId);
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
  },

  render: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

Otherwise, it won't *survive* the render cycle.

Comment: @DevinTryon when i call clearInterval(this.state.intervalId) it set the value of intervalId to 'undefined' but still refreshState function is called after 1 second

Comment: Did you add the `this.setState`?

Comment: @Devintryon In function componentDidMount i do 'this.setState({intervalId: setInterval(this.refreshStats, 3000)});' and in refreshSate 'clearInterval(this.state.inervalId)'

Comment: You have a typo: `this.state.inervalId`: should be `this.state.intervalId`.

Comment: No there is no typo issue

Comment: @DavinTryon what about saving it directly on `this`? Is it an anti-pattern?

Comment: There is problem with `setState` in `componentDidMount` (see [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md#prevent-usage-of-setstate-in-componentdidmount-reactno-did-mount-set-state)). "Updating the state after a component mount will trigger a second render() call and can lead to property/layout thrashing."  So, maybe saving it directly on `this` is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you need to run a command in an interval using window.setInterval.

When you navigate away from the component (to simulate unmounting), the interval still runs.

Even worse, when you navigate back to Greeting component, another interval process starts!

How to Fix the Issue
You need to save the interval ID when you call the setInterval

```
class Example extends Component {
  intervalID = 0;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(this.hello, 1000);
  }
  ...
}
```

To cancel setInterval, you need to call clearInterval, which require the interval ID returned when you called setInterval.

The best place to do is right before the component unmounts (componentWillUnmount).

```
class Example extends Component {
  intervalID = 0;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(this.hello, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by using clearInterval on the internal Id from the object returned.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.interval = setInterval(this.timer, 1000)
  console.log(this.interval) // Timeout {_id: 5, _clearFn: ƒ}
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval._id)
}
```

Comment: idk why, but this worked for me, really strange. I'm using `setInterval` to poll an external API every 5 minutes using React 16.

Comment: I have an auto-import extension in VSC that wrote `import { setInterval } from 'timers'` for me, I'm thinking maybe this import is changing the behavior of `setInterval`

Comment: For me it was also the `import { setInterval } from 'timers'` that messed it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass interval id.
If you log this.intervalId it will object.

So your code should be like:
clearInterval(this.intervalId._id);

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this example:
https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef#referencing-a-value-with-a-ref

Since you do not want to trigger a re-render for your state change, it is better to use a ref.

In a class component you can use this in your constructor

```
this.intervalRef = React.createRef();
```

For a functional component:

```
const intervalRef = useRef();
```