# Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component while calling api inside setInterval (React Native)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have been working on a app where I need to make an API call every 30s and set the response in some state. I am doing it inside setInterval. I have a component which is rendered on all the screens in the app. (same component where setInterval is). Everything seems to work but when I press back button to go to previous screen, I get this warning 'setState on unmounted component'. Remember, the component is mounted again in this screen also. Enough with the words, let me have the code here.

SongActivityBar.js

```
componentDidMount(){
  _isMounted = true
  this._timer = true;
  this.startPolling();
}


  componentWillUnMount() {
    _isMounted = false;
    this._timer && clearInterval(this._timer);
    this._timer = false;
  }

  startPolling=() => {
      if (_isMounted){
          this.fetchNowPlaying(); // do it once and then start it up ...
          this._timer = setInterval(() => this.fetchNowPlaying(), 30000);
      }
  }


 fetchNowPlaying() {
    fetch(url, {
    .......... 
    .then( (response) => {
      this._timer && this.setState({loading: false, nowPlaying: response.Message});
    ........
    });
  }
```

As clicking on any screen of the app, the component SongActivityBar.js is loaded, coming back to any screen with nav.pop() or android back button gives me this warning.

P.S: I am using Navigator for navigating between screens (can't change the library right now)

```
React Native version - 0.45.1
```

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that somehow the setTimeout is not cleared when you are going back. But im not sure why.

Answer (score 5):

You need to keep the timer in state in order to keep it alive during the lifecycle of component :

```js
componentDidMount(){
  this.fetchNowPlaying();
  const timer = setInterval(this.fetchNowPlaying, 30000);
  this.setState({ timer });
}

componentWillUnMount() {
  clearInterval(this.state.timer);
}
```

Reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023308/clearinterval-is-not-working-in-reactjs).